# "record amounts" and "only possible because"

Tags: phrases

From [NPR](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=276458973)

***INTRODUCTION***: This passage mainly describes a record-breaking rain in Britain. Prime Minister David promised that money is no object in the flood response, but in the mean time, hundreds of environment agency workers who respond to the floods were laid off. According to this, Labour leader Ed Miliband suspected that there is not enough money in fact. BTW Shapiro is the NPR correspondent.

> ED MILIBAND: If money is no object as he said, is he committing now to reconsider these redundancies?
>
> SHAPIRO:Cameron would not make that commitment. He said the U.K. is spending ***record amounts*** on flood prevention, and that's ***only*** possible because the government has made other tough choices on spending.

1. What's the meaning of *record amounts*? Does it mean the amounts are on record or the amounts are the highest in history?
2. Does the word *only* is relevant to *because*? I know a phrase called *only because*, meaning *something happens or possible for a particular reason***. But the word *possible* in the middle of the two words make me suspect that the word *only* is not relevant to *because* but to *possible*. In other words, is there any phrase like *only possible* without because following it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Record amounts* means “amounts which constitute a record”—as you say, the highest amounts in history.

*Only because* is not a fixed phrase, it is only a happenstance collocation of the two words. The adverb *only*, means approximately “this and no other” or ”this and no more“. Where it should be placed in a sentence like this has been controversial for a long time. There are two broad schools of thought on the subject:

1. The Traditional school holds that *only* precedes the constituent it modifies and argues:

   - that in this case the clear meaning is that the Government's spending is possible “for this reason, and no other”;
   - that *only* should therefore be placed before *because*, which is the term it modifies;
   - and that placing *only* before *possible* would imply that what is meant is “possible, and not something else such as *likely*  or *certain*”.
2. The Modern school holds

   - that  *only* does not modify *because*, but the entire predicate with its qualification *is possible because &c*, bearing thus the sense *is not otherwise possible than because &c*;
   - that the proper place for *only* is therefore immediately after the copula *is*, which does not ordinarily accept a pre-positioned modifier;
   - and that this parsing is sanctioned by universal practice, since nobody except a handful of fatuous self-constituted ‘experts’ with no authority whatever puts *only* where the Traditional school calls for it to be placed.

My own opinion is that although in some cases the Traditional principle (*only* precedes the constituent it modifies) **must** be followed in order to avoid ambiguity, in this case there is no such ambiguity and it makes no difference at all whether you put *only* before or after *possible*.

Comment: I think my opinion is exactly the same as yours. The Traditional position must be to some extent wrong/incomplete, because it debars too many constructions that many or even most native speakers are perfectly happy with. It's worth noting that in OP's specific example, if we needed to "force" the less likely (but "formally/strictly" implicit) interpretation whereby ***only** did in fact modify **possible***, we'd do that by placing exaggerated stress on ***possible**,* and leaving a slightly longer pause after it than normal. Thus making it blindingly clear it's the *only* word being modified.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly; although I have to admit that I myself, in speaking or writing, put *only* in the Traditional position. It is difficult to overcome the advantages of a good education.

Comment: There's no reason why you change - [you still have the majority behind you in the US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=possible+only+because%2Conly+possible+because&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpossible%20only%20because%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20possible%20because%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ... [it's us Brits who are pushing for change](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=possible+only+because%2Conly+possible+because&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpossible%20only%20because%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20possible%20because%3B%2Cc0) (more accurately, we've always accepted both forms). But once the pressure to fall into line with US usage dies off (as seems to be happening), I think it's very likely the ***only possible because*** version will actually become far more obviously the ***favoured*** one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As you may see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=possible+only+because%2Conly+possible+because%2Cpossible+only+because+%2B+only+possible+because&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpossible%20only%20because%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20possible%20because%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28possible%20only%20because%20%2B%20only%20possible%20because%29%3B%2Cc0) we're resolving the problem by ceasing to address it.

Comment: Ah, but I would obviously say *it's **only** possible for you to post that link **because** you're better at using expressions in NGrams than me*. You, on the other hand, would have to maintain that *it's possible for you to do that **only because** of your superior NGram-fu*. Take heart though! Apparently you're the first person on the planet to be [acknowledged as having **NGram-fu**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22NGram-fu%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22NGram-fu%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6289j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). (Will this exact comment be there soon? :)